# Java Code Not reachable

Tags: java

Please have a look on my code its showing code not reachable.

```
private static void createUser() {
    HashMap<String, String> membership = new HashMap<String, String>();
    System.out.println("Enter the Name of the User: ");
    String nameOfUser=sc.next();
    System.out.println("Enter the Membership tier which you prefer");
    System.out.println("1. Member - 5 % discount \n 2. Bronze - 10 % discount \n 3. Silver - 15% discount \n "
            + "4. Gold - 20 % discount \n 5. Platinum - 25 % discount");
    String typeOfMembership = null;
    while(true){
        int memberChoice=sc.nextInt();
        switch(memberChoice){
            case 1:
                typeOfMembership="Member";
                membership.put(nameOfUser,typeOfMembership);
                break;
            case 2:
                typeOfMembership="Bronze";
                membership.put(nameOfUser,typeOfMembership);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Please select one of the available Member Type.");
        }
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : membership.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Member Created Successfully with name "+entry.getKey()+" and "+entry.getValue()+" tier.");
    }
}
```

Its showing code unreachable from this line onwards

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : membership.entrySet()) {
```

Comment: The `break;` in your `switch`-`case` will not break out of the `while` loop

Answer (score 5):

You have an infinite loop     `while(true)` so you will never reach the for loop.

Note: the `break`s you have will only break the `switch`.

**Suggestion:**
One way to fix it is to exchange the hard coded `true`, to something like `isMemberSelected` that you set to false in the default case.  You could probably also switch to a `do-while`-loop.

You could even break it out to a separate method `memberships = createMembers();`

Comment: Nice suggestions, +1 from me! One more alternative is giving the while-loop a label and breaking that label (i.e. `whileLoop: while(true){ ... case 1: ... break whileLoop; }`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an infinite loop at `while(true)` this will always evaluate to true hence the execution of the script will stay in the loop. Try a different loop guard which shouldn't always evaluate to `true`.